# How to show equality of this $e$ estimation?

Tags: analysis

Writing it exactly as in book:

$1 + \frac{1}{1!}+ \frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{n!n}=3 -\frac{1}{1*2*2!} -  ... - \frac{1}{(n-1)*n*n!}$

How to derive RHS out of first? I tried to sum up left side but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere

**It is not sequences that converge to e**. They give approximate value of e for real n. You can forget about e if you like (I don't think it is key here) and question is how to derive one of other (or proof their equality).

[image: photo from textbook in case I wrote it wrong here]

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, it is estimation sequence, not representing real e. And you can check that equality is true with n=1,2,3 ... etc.

Comment: I still have the same objection. Take a huge $n$. The LHS approaches $e$, the RHS approaches $3$, and $3\neq e$.

Comment: from where does that equality comes?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizi, I don't know, I made a photo of exact how it looks in book exercise

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, ok, i think I got it wrong, I updated version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so we have to show that:
$$ \frac{1}{n\cdot n!}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!} = 3-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdot(k+1)!}. \tag{1}$$
Easy way: induction on $n$. It is straightforward to check that the given identity holds for $n=1$.
It follows that we just need to prove that:
$$ \frac{1}{(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!}=-\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+1)!}\tag{2} $$
and that is simple, since it is equivalent to:
$$ n-(n+1)^2+n(n+1)+1 = 0.\tag{3} $$
Now that $a)$ is proved, it is enough to apply $\lim_{n\to +\infty}$ to both sides of $(1)$ to get:
$$ e = 3-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdot(n+2)!}.\tag{4} $$
as wanted. An independent proof of $(4)$ may go through the following lines:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\frac{1}{(n+2)!} = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n-x^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}\,dx =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(e^x-1-x)(1-x)}{x^2}\,dx$$
where the last integral equals $3-e=\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)e^{x}\,dx$.